# Передача аргументов в абстрактный класс Java

Tags: java

Имеются классы - Student, Mentor, Teacher и тд. Каждый обьект класса имеет метод getName() к примеру.  Имеются также классы DAO для каждого из этих классов для того, чтобы создавать обьекты этих классов из файла csv, записывать их и тд. Хочу сделать в классе абстрактном один метод для всех DAO - например save(), но этот метод должен знать с каким обьектом работать. Каким образом передать в абстрактный класс обьект так, чтобы абстрактный класс распознал его, cейчас он может распознать методы только обьекта который я задекларирую.

Пример одного из DAO:

```
public class DAOMentor extends DAOAbstract implements mentorDaoInterface {

private static final File f = new File("src/csv/Mentors.csv");
private static final String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
private static final Mentor mentor = new Mentor();

public DAOMentor() {
    super(mentor, path);
}
```

Абстрактный класс:

```
public abstract class DAOAbstract {

String path;
Mentor Person;


public DAOAbstract(Mentor person, String path){
    this.path = path;
    this.Person = person;
}

Person.getName() - видит
```

Возможно сделать что-то вроде этого? :

```
public abstract class DAOAbstract {

String path;
Object Person;


public DAOAbstract(Object person, String path){
    this.path = path;
    this.Person = person;
}

Person.getName() - не видит
```

Comment: Переменные надо с маленькой буквы именовать. Иначе будет аццкая путаница и ошибки компиляции А по вопросу - скастуйте объект к нужному типу: `((Person)Person).getName()`. Также, возможно, вам следует знать про оператор `instanceof` - проверяет сответствие типа левой части и класса справа. Например `if(Person instance of Mentor)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сконструировать что-то типа:

```
public abstract class DAOAbstract {

String path;
Person person;


public DAOAbstract(Person person, String path){
    this.path = path;
    this.person = person;
}
```

Где класс `Person` является суперклассом всех классов `Student`, `Mentor` и `Teacher`:

```
public abstract class Person {
    public abstract String getName();
}
```

Comment: Но ведь по сути тогда получается , что мы будем вызывать методы класса абстрактного?

Comment: да, а что вас смущает?

Comment: По правилам ведь нельзя напрямую вызывать его методы?

Comment: @ValekPotapov вы даже не представляете насколько вы неправы :)

Comment: @Valek Potapov че за правила? :) Метод будет дергаться у конкретного объекта. Этот объект принадлежит не абстрактному классу, а конкретному (Student, Mentor, Teacher). Там функция getName() определена.

Comment: @learp, согласен, уже понял и все сделал :)

Comment: @Barmaley , благодарю, сделал все как надо с Вашей подсказкой